Footer won't display at the bottom of page
I'm trying to create a website for a school project, but I'm stuck at making the footer display just at the bottom of the page, so you can only see it when scrolling down completely. If I use position: absolute; and bottom: 0;, it's displaying on my .videooverlay.
Codepen: https://codepen.io/elijahzyx/pen/bGJXOgZ
I tried all the different position options on my .footer, but none have worked.


@font-face {
  font-family: 'KGRedHands';
  src: url("media/KGRedHands.ttf");
}

body {
  background-color: #fbf4e8;
  font-family: 'KGRedHands';
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(14.2px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(14.2px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#logoklein {
  float: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 4px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.headervideo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.videooverlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.download {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 5px;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) translateX(-50%);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-20px) translateX(-50%);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-15px) translateX(-50%);
  }
}

.arrowdown {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite, fadein 2s;
}

.arrowdown img {
  width: 60px;
  height: auto;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .logo {
    width: 250px;
  }
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 105%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.content h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  #youtubetrailer {
    max-width: 70vw;
    max-height: 50vh;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .logo {
    width: 250px;
  }
}

.spielprinzip,
.traumfarm,
.interagieren,
.orte {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

#greg {
  max-width: 65vh;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #greg {
    display: none;
  }
}

.footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(14.2px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(14.2px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer .footertextlinks {
  font-family: 'KGRedHands';
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer .footertextlinks p {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.icons {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  align-items: center;
}

.icons img {
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.icons img:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.footer .footertextlinks a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hay Day</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="media/icon.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <img id="logoklein" src="media/logoklein.png" alt="Logo klein">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="subpages/wiki.html">Wiki</a>
    <a href="subpages/guide.html">Leitfaden für Eltern</a>
  </div>

  <div class="top">
    <video class="headervideo" autoplay loop muted src="media/header.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
    <img class="logo" src="media/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <img class="videooverlay" src="media/bgtop2.png" alt="Overlay">
    <div class="download">
      <a href="https://apps.apple.com/de/app/hay-day/id506627515" target="_blank"><img src="media/download_apple.svg" alt="Download on Apple"></a>
      <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.hayday" target="_blank"><img src="media/download_google.svg" alt="Download on Google"></a>
      <a href="https://www.amazon.de/Supercell-ltd-Hay-Day/dp/B018GSK5ZC" target="_blank"><img src="media/download_amazon.svg" alt="Download on Amazon"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="arrowdown" onclick="scrollToContent()">
      <img src="media/arrowdown.png" alt="Pfeil nach unten">
    </div>
    <script>
      function scrollToContent() {
        var content = document.querySelector('.content');
        window.scrollTo({
          top: content.offsetTop,
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
      }
    </script>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="tailer">
      <h1>Schaue den Hay Day Trailer</h1>
      <iframe id="youtubetrailer" width="896" height="502.4" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yVvkrYyb8fw?si=uSgA7BsGCQDS2ukJ" title="YouTube video player" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <img id="greg" src="media/greg.png" alt="Greg">
      <p>Entdecke die wunderbare Welt von Hay Day, dem beliebten Farmspiel, das Millionen von Spielern begeistert! Tauche ein in eine idyllische Landschaft, in der du deine eigene Farm verwalten und gestalten kannst.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="spielprinzip">
      <h1>Das Spielprinzip</h1>
      <p>In Hay Day beginnt der Spieler mit einer kleinen Farm, die er nach und nach ausbaut, indem er verschiedene landwirtschaftliche Produkte anbaut und erntet. Zu den angebauten Produkten gehören klassische Farmwaren wie Weizen, Mais, Karotten und Erdbeeren.
        Mit fortschreitendem Spiel können Spieler auch Obstbäume wie Apfel- und Kirschbäume sowie Nutzpflanzen wie Baumwolle und Zuckerrohr anbauen.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="traumfarm">
      <h1>Baue deine Traumfarm</h1>
      <p>Deiner Kreativität sind keine Grenzen gesetzt, wenn es darum geht, deine Traumfarm zu gestalten. Beginne damit, deine Felder zu bestellen und süße Tiere zu züchten, die deine Farm bevölkern werden. Von frischen Produkten wie Mais und Karotten bis
        hin zu köstlichen Milchprodukten von glücklichen Kühen - die Auswahl liegt ganz bei dir.</p>
      <img id="farm" src="media/farm.PNGg" alt="Beispiel Farm">
    </div>
    <div class="interagieren">
      <h1>Interagiere mit deinen Freunden</h1>
      <p>Schließe dich mit deinen Freunden zusammen, um Handel zu treiben, an aufregenden Events teilzunehmen und euch gegenseitig auf euren Farmen zu unterstützen. Tauscht Ressourcen und Produkte aus, helft euch bei der Erfüllung von Bestellungen und besucht
        einander, um eure Fortschritte zu bewundern und Tipps auszutauschen. Mit Freunden macht das Landleben in Hay Day gleich noch mehr Spaß!</p>
      <img id="shop" src="media/shop.PNGg" alt="Ingame Shop">
    </div>
    <div class="orte">
      <h1>Entdecke neue Orte</h1>
      <p>Abseits deiner Farm gibt es auch andere interessante Orte zu erkunden. Besuche den Markt, um mit anderen Spielern Handel zu treiben und seltene Gegenstände zu finden. Begib dich zur Stadt, um Bestellungen zu erfüllen und Belohnungen zu verdienen.
        Oder besuche den Angelteich, um exotische Fische zu fangen und besondere Belohnungen zu erhalten.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footertextlinks">
      <p>&#169; <a href="https://supercell.com/en/" target="_blank">Supercell</a> 2024</p>
      <a href="https://supercell.com/en/terms-of-service/" target="_blank">Nutzungsbedingungen</a>
    </div>
    <div class="icons">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/HayDayOfficial/?locale=de_DE" target="_blank"><img src="media/socialicons/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hayday/?hl=de" target="_blank"><img src="media/socialicons/instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/hayday" target="_blank"><img src="media/socialicons/x.png" alt="X"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/@hayday" target="_blank"><img src="media/socialicons/youtube.png" alt="YouTube"></a>
      <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@hayday?lang=de-DE" target="_blank"><img src="media/socialicons/tiktok.png" alt="TikTok"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Pls share your HTML code. Check to which element your footer is relative if you use position absolute

Try adding height: 100%; to body

although your question is not fully clear due to missing of HTML but i think you need to define the Body tag height 100% .

@Mehdi sure, here it is: https://codepen.io/elijahzyx/pen/bGJXOgZ

@AustinPoulson that didn't work unfortunately

@Elijah Just a heads up, try to avoid linking off site for questions and answers if possible. I added the html to your question. Do it like that in the future :)

@AustinPoulson Please do not copy code from elsewhere without the author's consent. The copyrights are different between CodePen and SO. Also IF you get permission to do what OP should have done themselves, please click the [<>] snippet editor so we have a [mcve]
